# Return value of scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

Here is my code to repeatedly read three variables separated by whitespace from user. The format of input should be 'char int int'(e.g b 3 3 ). I use the return value of scanf function to ensure input is exactly three variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int x, y, nargs;
  char command;

  while(1){
    nargs = scanf("%c %d %d", &command, &x, &y);
    printf("%d\n",nargs);

    if(nargs != 3){
      printf("error\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input and Output:

```
g 4 4
3
b 3 3
1
error
```

The first line input is no problem. But when I input second line, it shows scanf() only read one variable from this line. What's the problem of my code?

Comment: `" %c%d%d"` is the quick answer.  Using `fgets()` and then `sscanf(buf, " %c%d%d",...` is better.  GTG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `\n` newline hidden between the two input lines you are sending to stdin. After first `scanf` you have a `'\n'` pending on the input stream, then you append `"b 3 3"` so the whole buffer looks like `"\nb 3 3"`.

Then `scanf` is called again and `\n` is matched to `%c`, after `scanf` expects whitespace but the buffer has `'b'` so it fails after assigning `\n` to `command`.

You could try matching with

```
nargs = scanf("%c %d %d ", &command, &x, &y);
                       ^
```

so that newline is eaten with the previous `scanf`, from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

> any single whitespace character in the format string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from the input

Comment: Got it! But there is a new problem, it can not read my first line input. I should input g 4 4\n b 3 3\n then the program feedback 3 to me.

Comment: Use `" %c%d%d"` not `"%c %d %d "`  Space needed at beginning.  At end has problems.

Answer (score -2):

```
nargs = scanf("%1s %d %d", &command, &x, &y);
```

The problem is with the `%c` for one character. If you change it for `%1s` you expect an string of one character (the same) but without problems.

With the `%c` it is better to send the result to an array, and access the content with its index.

Comment: `"%1s"` is a bad idea with `char command;` -  Buffer overrun.

Comment: To expand on @chux's comment, `%1s` reads into a one-character *string*, which occupies two bytes, one for the data and one for the `'\0'` terminator.